# Setting script to run at user login on Azure VM via ARM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, vhd

I have generalized a windows Azure image and I am using it in an ARM (Azure resoure manager) template to create a new VM. At the time of VM creation I am doing some bootstrapping work using Custom Script extension that runs a Powershell script. It works fine except for few things that are specific to a user that will log on to machine. For example, I can't map a network drive or set powershell exection policty to remotesigned for the user who will log in to the machine via Custom Script Extension.

Is there a way to accomplish user specific tasks in the ARM template or set some scripts to run when user will log in?

Comment: Do you want to run a login script to set those things?  Or do you want to configure those things in the Custom Script Extension?

Comment: If I can do all the work in Custom Script Extension it will be great as it will be in one place. I am executing a PowerShell script for the Custom Script Extension, as I understand my PS Custom Script runs under SYSTEM account. I need to mount a network drive and setup environment for a different user who will log in to the VM after extension has run. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could do it in the CSE - and while I'm certainly not an expert here, I suspect that if you do that, you will have to set it up for all users that log on to the VM, not just a single user.  Does that work for the scenario?

Comment: Can I set a network drive mapping for all the users in a PowerShell script executed by CSE ? I tried but I don't see it working. Perhaps I need to impersonate the other user?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the space but can dig in some - what code did you try that wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I am using sth similar to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/automating-sql-server-vm-configuration-using-custom-script-extension/):

> However, we can’t directly hand this script to Custom Script Extension yet. Custom Script Extension uses NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM account to execute scripts, but the account doesn’t have necessary privileges to execute the SQL configuration commands. To work around this, we’ll create a separate bootstrap script, which impersonates an administrator account before invokes the script.

Here is the code used:

```
$password =  ConvertTo-SecureString "[your admin account user password]" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$env:COMPUTERNAME\[your admin account]", $password)
$command = $file = $PSScriptRoot + "\CustomScriptSQLPS.ps1"
Enable-PSRemoting –force
Invoke-Command -FilePath $command -Credential $credential -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
Disable-PSRemoting -Force
```

I don't know if remoting is relevant for this though ...

Credits to [Haishi Bai](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/author/hbai/)

Comment: I'm trying to solve this exact problem.  I have a powershell script that creates a database in a sql server base image and then add a CLR and stored proc.  It creates the DB just fine using powershell, but it fails to add the CLR and sproc using the Invoke-Sqlcmd.  I'm curious how you passed two ps1 files in as custom extensions, but having only one do the bootstrapping.  Wouldn't they both execute as part of the startup?  I just want the bootstrap script to run which launches the other script, but both need to be copied into the VM.